# Send file to server through iText PDF?

Tags: file, pdf, itext, send

I'm dynamically creating some PDF files through my application, using iText, and I need to use several components (TextField, CheckBox, RadioButtons etc), and then submit the values to server. But, one of the requirements says that the user needs to be able to select and send files along with the other values. I did not find a specific component to this, and so I'm asking for some help with this situation.

Is there a way to create some kind of Input File, File Chooser, etc, and attach it on the generated PDF file? And then send this selected file to server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in the official documentation, more specifically in the example [FdfServlet](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=171) of chapter 9 of my [book](http://itextpdf.com/book). However, in this example, we add a file selection field to an existing PDF, so I've made you an example that explains how to create such a field when creating a document from scratch: [FileSelectionExample](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/FileSelectionExample)

A file selection field is created just like any other text field, except that you have to set a flag using the `setOptions()` method. If you want a file chooser to appear, you also have to add a JavaScript action:

```
TextField file = new TextField(writer, new Rectangle(36, 788, 559, 806), "myfile");
file.setOptions(TextField.FILE_SELECTION);
PdfFormField upload = file.getTextField();
upload.setAdditionalActions(PdfName.U, PdfAction.javaScript(
            "this.getField('myfile').browseForFileToSubmit();", writer));
writer.addAnnotation(upload);
```

In the full example, I also added a second field and after selecting the file with the `browseForFileToSubmit()` method, I set the focus to that other field. I'm doing this because the file name only becomes visible in the file selection field after that field loses focus.

Comment: Bruno, thanks for you answers, it really helped me with the field. However, I'm having some problems getting the file on the server side. I suspect it's some issue with the submit button, or even the created PDF. I'm currently using the submit as this: submit.setAction(PdfAction.createSubmitForm(url, null, 0)); but the file field return as null. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: In fact, it worked now. I changed the lib for a more recent one and I tried the example. The only issue now is how to get the file name, but I think it's manageable. Thanks!